# Iterating over a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary where the keys are integers and the values are strings. The dictionary has been sorted using key values.
I need to copy the corresponding **string** values (keeping the sorted order) to a list. I cannot figure out how to iterate over the dictionary.

I know the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary (let it be 'n').

```
    Some_ordered_dict
    resultant_list=[]
    for i in range(n):
        resultant_list.append(Some_ordered_dict[increment-key?]
```

The dictionary was sorted using OrderedDict from some dictionary 'dic' as follows;

```
    od=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items()))
```

The essential point is that I have to display the strings values of the dictionary in the same order as they appear in the sorted dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries have no order.

Comment: Are you using an `OrderedDict` to begin with? If you want to iterate over a dictionary use `iteritems` in python 2 or just `items` in python 3.

Comment: If you built the OrderedDict from `sorted(dic.items())`, why not just iterate over `sorted(dic.items())` directly?

Comment: Its just `od.values()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
resultant_list = [d[k] for k in sorted(d)]
```

Comment: Unpacking this a little - iterating over a dictionary iterates over the keys, so `sorted(d)` is a sorted iterable of the dictionary keys.

Comment: Yes; that is a helpful comment @PeterDeGlopper. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Python dictionary does not guarantee that items in a dictionary will be kept in any order. Next thing is that you have to iterate using a "for in" statement like such:

```
Some_ordered_dict
    resultant_list=[]
    for i in Some_ordered_dict:
        resultant_list.append(Some_ordered_dict[i])
```

You should take a look at [the ordered dict collection](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to ensure that the items on your dict are kept in the order that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard unordered dictionary in python you could use something like this:

```
resultant_list = []
for i in sorted(dict.keys()):
    resultant_list.append(dict[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other posts, dictionaries do not guarantee order. One way to get a sorted list would be to created a list of tuples out of your dict's (key, value) pairs, then sort this list based n the first element(the key), as follows:

```
my_dict = {2: 'two', 3: 'three', 1: 'one'}
my_tuple_list = list(zip(my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values()))
my_sorted_list = sorted(my_tuple_list, key = lambda item: item[0])
resultant_list = [x[1] for x in my_sorted_list]
```

Comment: `my_tuple_list` is just `my_dict.items()` (or `list(my_dict.items())` on 3.x, or you can just leave it as an iterable). For `my_sorted_list`, you'll get minor efficiency gains from using `import operator; my_sorted_list = sorted(my_tuple_list, key=operator.itemgetter(0))`. I would use `resultant_list = [v for (k, v) in my_sorted_list]` but that's just taste. Or to sum up, `my_dict = {...}; resultant_list = [v for (k, v) in sorted(my_dict, key=operator.itemgetter(0))]`